# Rails 3 script to create model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a runner script to build a model. The model is this:

```
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :slots
  attr_accessible  :available, :day_date, :venue
end

class Slot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :day
end
```

I would like to make 100 blank Days with 9 Slots for each Day. This is runner script load_days.rb

```
Day.transaction do
  (1..100).each do |i|
   days = Date.today+i
   Day.create( :available => "Available", :venue => "Pitch_1", :day_date => days )
   (1..9).each to |j|
      hours = days.hours+j
      id = Day.id
      Slot.create ( :time_slot => hours , :day_id => id )
  end
 end
end
```

I am getting the following error:
script/load_days.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
      Slot.create ( :time_slot => hours , :day_id => id )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling .id on the Day class instead of the Day object you created, this should work:

```
Day.transaction do
  (1..100).each do |i|
   days = Date.today+i
   day = Day.create( :available => "Available", :venue => "Pitch_1", :day_date => days )
   (1..9).each to |j|
      hours = days.hours+j
      id = day.id
      Slot.create ( :time_slot => hours , :day_id => id )
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: there also seems to be the line `(1..9).each to |j|` which should be `(1..9).each do |j|`

Comment: that fixed it thanks. As well as Matthews comment i also had to fix       hours = (time)+j.hours